# Matlab MEX C++ Efficient way to pass an input sparse array's parameters to std::vectors

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I would like to know how to extract the values from a `matlab::data::SparseArray<T>` to `std::vector`s efficiently.

As a minimum working example of what I would like to achieve, consider a MEX function that receives one sparse array of doubles as input and returns another sparse array with its nonzero values equal to double the input's values:

```cpp
#include "mex.hpp"
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"
#include <vector>
class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function
{
public:
    void operator() (matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs)
    {
        // get the input
        matlab::data::SparseArray<double> spArrayInp = std::move(inputs[0]);

        // copy the input sparse matrix information to std::vectors
        size_t nnzSpIn = spArrayInp.getNumberOfNonZeroElements();
        auto dim = spArrayInp.getDimensions();
        std::vector<int> rows(nnzSpIn), cols(nnzSpIn);
        std::vector<double> vals(nnzSpIn);

        // *******  IMPROVE THIS  ******* //
        auto idx = spArrayInp.getIndex(spArrayInp.begin()); // std::pair<size_t, size_t>
        size_t itr=0;
        for (matlab::data::TypedIterator<double> inpSpArrayPtr = spArrayInp.begin(); inpSpArrayPtr != spArrayInp.end(); ++inpSpArrayPtr)
        {
            idx = spArrayInp.getIndex(inpSpArrayPtr);
            rows[itr] = idx.first;
            cols[itr] = idx.second;
            vals[itr++] = *inpSpArrayPtr;
        }
        // ******  ******  ******  ****** //

        // double the values
        std::for_each(vals.begin(),vals.end(),[](double &a){a*=2;});

        // output doubled sparse matrix
        matlab::data::ArrayFactory factory;

        auto data_p = factory.createBuffer<double>(nnzSpIn);
        auto rows_p = factory.createBuffer<size_t>(nnzSpIn);
        auto cols_p = factory.createBuffer<size_t>(nnzSpIn);

        double* dataPtr = data_p.get();
        size_t* rowsPtr = rows_p.get();
        size_t* colsPtr = cols_p.get();

        std::for_each(vals.begin(), vals.end(), [&](const double& e) { *(dataPtr++) = e; });
        std::for_each(rows.begin(), rows.end(), [&](const size_t& e) { *(rowsPtr++) = e; });
        std::for_each(cols.begin(), cols.end(), [&](const size_t& e) { *(colsPtr++) = e; });

        outputs[0] = factory.createSparseArray<double>({dim[0],dim[1]}, nnzSpIn, std::move(data_p),
                        std::move(rows_p), std::move(cols_p));
    }
};
```

I tried at least to do the following to improve performance

```cpp
vals.assign(spArrayInp.begin(), spArrayInp.end());
```

but that crashed MATLAB when compiling with MEX C++.

Comment: Sparse matrix in MATLAB internally represented as CSC format and [C MEX interface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-sparse-arrays.html) allows to directly access that structure, so it is possibly more efficient.

Comment: @rahnema1 Is it possible to mix C MEX interface with C++ code? And I couldn't find a similar representation in the [Sparse array class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.data.sparsearray.html).

Comment: I'm not sure but I think C MEX interface  cannot be mixed with C++ interface. But you can use C MEX interface in a C++ program and use std::vector.

Comment: Guess I'll have to learn how to use the C MEX interface, then! Do you reckon the gain in performance is significant, in comparison to the code in my question (for a very large sparse matrix)? Plus, I wonder if I can use `std::move` for the `ir` and `jc` arrays. Or I could just use these arrays directly, without intermediate `std::vector`s, I guess... Edit: oh, never mind, `std::move` doesn't work for POD

Comment: Please be cautious of using std::move. For example if you saved your code in file myfunction.cpp and in MATLAB called it as `B = myfunction (A);` You cannot use `A` from this point forward because you have moved `A` .Instead you should call the function as `A = myfunction (A);` to make `A` usable. In your example code since don't want to change the input and after that assign it to the same variable you shouldn't use `move` and std::vector here is unnecessary and you can directly write to the output buffer.

Comment: Moreover you need to profile your code and find _real_ bottlenecks and then try to improve them. In the example that you have provided I think it is more simple and efficient to use `B = A .* 2;`  or `A = A .* 2;` instead of writing a `MEX` function. In other cases if `MEX` improves for example just a few seconds don't use C/C++.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize `A` would not be usable afterwards. And, yes, I guess I'll just have to profile to know for sure. I actually intend to pass the sparse matrix and use cuSPARSE and cuSOLVER with it, with mexcuda. The doubling thing was just for the MWE. The issue is that I don't believe I can pass the data of the sparse matrix directly to the GPU without intermediate arrays using the C++ interface. Your C MEX interface suggestion would be ideal. Unnecessary copies could be avoided.

Comment: Plus, [apparently I'm trying to reinvent the wheel](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/gpu-cuda-and-mex-programming.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav).